# Any reason my Facebook Like button pops out a Comment Box?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any reason my Facebook LIKE used to display a normal BOX and NOW …it shows transparent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739699/any-reason-my-facebook-like-used-to-display-a-normal-box-and-now-it-shows-tra)

I'm not sure if I have this right, but I intended to add a "LIKE" button
where the user will simply  like the site and that's it.

As soon as you click on the LIKE button, it seems to display a Comment box
and anything you type displays on your wall. Even if you don't type anything,
you get the Wall entry.

Anyone can highlight what am I doing wrong here?

I added this on the BODY

```
<div id="fb-root">
</div>
<script>        
    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxxxxxxx";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

and this on the actual button location

```
<div style="padding-top: 8px;" class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.WinePassionate.com"
    data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="50" data-show-faces="false"
    data-font="verdana">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of the Facebook like button that you can't turn off. There is a slight work around if you want. This is taken from their FAQ:

**When will users have the option to add a comment to the like?**

If you are using the XFBML version of the Like button, users will always have the option to add a comment. If you are using the Iframe version of the button, users will have the option to comments if you are using the 'standard' layout with a width of at least 400 pixels. If users do add a comment, the story published back to Facebook is given more prominence.

So basically it means that you can if you switch to iframe and make it less than 400px wide or iframe and change the layout to something other than standard.